# go to top button Rmarkdown/Html

Tags: html, r-markdown

I would like to add a `circle-arrow-up` from [fontawesome](https://fontawesome.com/search?q=circle%20arrow%20up&s=solid%2Cbrands). Somehow `arrow-up` is working but not `circle-arrow-up`. And if it is possible to increase the size of the circle. How to get around this?

````
```{r load_packages, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE, include=FALSE} 
library(fontawesome)
```     

Back to top [`r fa("arrow-up", fill = "steelblue")`](#)
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some Reason it wasn't working, but then all of a sudden it rendered for me. Maybe suggest clearing any R Session info, if you have another computer you can try this same code.

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: html_document
---

```{r load_packages, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE, include=FALSE} 
library(fontawesome)
```     

Back to top [`r fa("arrow-circle-up", fill = "steelblue")`](#)
````

[image]